# How to get items with the same column value

Tags: mysql, database

I have table

```
Products(color_keyword,color)
```

My goal is:

When I'm doing `

```
SELECT * 
  FROM Products
```

add to each product list of colors (it can be comma separated even) with the same **color_keyword**.

Is that possible somehow with database tools?

If not, maybe it's possible to reorganise database/tables to achieve this result.

I know that I can do it with foreaching each product returned in node.js and make for each product selection request with  `WHERE color_keyword=current_product_color_keyword`, but I'm looking for something more elegant solution.

Thanks.

Comment: Provide proper CREATE and INSERT statements and a desired result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use a correlated subquery, but be careful with large sets. The correlated subquery will get executed for each row returned by the outer query, so we want to ensure that suitable index is available. In terms of performance, this approach has the potential to eat our lunch and our lunch box too.

```
 SELECT p.id
      , p.color_keyword
      , p.color
      , ( SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT q.color ORDER BY q.color)
            FROM products q
           WHERE q.color_keyword <=> p.color_keyword
        ) AS color_list 
   FROM products p 
 WHERE ...
```

---

Another approach is to use a join to an inline view

```
 SELECT p.id
      , p.color_keyword
      , p.color
      , q.color_list
   FROM products p 
   LEFT
   JOIN ( SELECT r.color_keyword 
               , GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT r.color ORDER BY r.color) AS color_list
           FROM products r
          GROUP BY r.color_keyword
        ) q
     ON q.color_keyword <=> p.color_keyword  
 WHERE ...
```

Comment: @AlexanderSeredenko: note that the result returned by `GROUP_CONCAT` aggregate function is limited (in bytes) by setting of `group_concat_max_len` variable and `max_allowed_packet`... `SELECT @@group_concat_max_len`.  If the result exceeds the allowed maximum, MySQL will truncate the result to maximum allowed length, with no error or warning.